# Regex - lookahead / LookBehind assertion

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I want to test Regular expression on following text

```
  <div class="creditItem"><a href="/maren_addy/beauty-ful/"></a></div>      
<a href="abc.aspx">test</a>
<div class="creditItem"><a href="/maren_addy/beauty-ful2/"></a> </div>
```

Regular expression

> (?<=class="creditItem">.*?href=").*?(?=")

Expected Output

```
/maren_addy/beauty-ful/
/maren_addy/beauty-ful2/
```

But getting this output

```
/maren_addy/beauty-ful/
abc.aspx
/maren_addy/beauty-ful2/
```

can someone please explain and correct the regular expression

Thanks

Comment: If this is meant to be for HTML parsing, you would probably be better off looking for a dedicated library rather than Regex.

Comment: Don't use regex for HTML parsing. This is only a tip of the iceberg!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below regex,

```
(?<=class="creditItem"><a href=").*?(?=")
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zJ8eB3/2)

C# code would be,

```
String input = @"  <div class=""creditItem""><a href=""/maren_addy/beauty-ful/""></a></div>      
<a href=""abc.aspx"">test</a>
<div class=""creditItem""><a href=""/maren_addy/beauty-ful2/""></a> </div>  ";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=class=""creditItem""><a href="").*?(?="")");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/GStRpu)

Comment: If i will change Input string to like this <div class="creditItem">
 <a href="/maren_addy/beauty-ful/"></a> 
</div>  
<a href="abc.aspx">test</a>
<div class="creditItem">
 <a href="/maren_addy/beauty-ful2/"></a> 
</div> .. It won't work please check

Comment: `(?<=class="creditItem"> ?<a href=").*?(?=")` or `(?<=class="creditItem">\s*<a href=").*?(?=")` would match the both.

Comment: thanks it working fine .. can you please explain me why this was not working (?<=class="creditItem">.*?<a href=").*?(?=")

Answer (score 0):

Get the matched group from index 1

```
(?<=class="creditItem"><a href=")([^"]*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gE5cP2/1)

Read [Want to Be Lazy? Think Twice.](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html)